App Store Connect Issue with Business Section Agreements - Verifying Forever
I just enrolled into Apple Developer Program and I already paid $99 annual fee. I encountered an issue that I hope some of you might have experience with. When I accessed the Business section of the App Store Connect, where I found only two agreements available: the Free Apps Agreement and the Digital Services Act. I have signed both, and my dashboard now displays a banner stating, "The information provided is being verified. We will notify after it has been verified." I think they are verifying what was already verified during enrollment phase.
Both agreements are currently marked as Active and I can do nothing than to wait. Meanwhile, my business detail was fully verified and approved during enrollment. It's been multiple weeks with no further updates. It's blocking me from creating an APP.
Has anyone here faced a similar verification banner? If so, how long did it take?
I tried contacting Apple contact us, but the advisor didn't have any idea.
